# Safari: Prevent two print dialogs when printing an Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, safari

My site has a "print this page" button.

I load a static print template HTML file into a hidden iframe, copy the HTML into that page using jQuery, and call `window.print()` from the Iframe page. All is well, except on Safari, which wants to print the parent frame as well, so I get two print dialogs opening.

I've tried calling window.print from within the iframe, and calling it from the parent, targetting the iframe (`document.printFrame.window.print()`) but I get two dialogs regardless.

Does anyone know a way around this? I only want to print the Iframe, not the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Put this in said iframe:

```
function printPage() { print(); }
```

then in the parent:

```
function printIframe(id)
{
    var iframe = document.frames ? document.frames[id] : document.getElementById(id);
    var ifWin = iframe.contentWindow || iframe;
    iframe.focus();
    ifWin.printPage();
    return false;
}
```

Should this not work either, I'd try opening up a new window/tab, and fill it with the printable HTML.

```
var printwin = window.open("about:blank", "_new");
printwin.document.open();
printwin.document.write("HTML goes here..javascript which is going to print is in there too..");
printwin.document.close();
```

Two minor things to watch out for are

- split `</script>` in the new window, so you don't terminate prematurely
- use setTimeout() to execute after onLoad() has finished, otherwise Firefox users may see a blank page below the print dialog